# GUI interface to scan for local network public files

Tags: networking, scanning

What are the best tools out there, for mac, windows and linux, to scan a local area network for files?

I want the results to open the file directly and/or being able to easily select and copy.

edit: a Python / QT would be very welcomed here. :P

Comment: You want something to go out on the local subnet and find any AFP, SMB, and NFS servers (and FTP? and WebDAV?), connect to them as...Guest? As your user account? As a list of user accounts?...then mount or browse every share it finds, and index every file?

Comment: @Spiff AFP, SMP and NFS sure, FTP and WebDAV maybe. Yeah, connect as guest or the local user, don't need to be too fancy.